# How to create a Data Binding Adapter for Breeze

Tags: javascript, data-binding, breeze

From Breeze introduction...

> Breeze currently supports Knockout, BackBone, and AngularJS with adapters for other libraries on the way. We’d be happy to help you write an adapter for a library we don’t yet support.".

What other libraries are one the way?

Is there some documentation which describes what has to be done for other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't gotten around to documenting the **model library adapter api** YET, but Breeze ships with the three model library adapters that you mentioned.  You can look at the source to see how these are done.

On the Breeze zip look in the Scripts/Adapters folder for any files that begin ith "Breeze.modelLibrary".  You will also see *dataService* adapters and *ajax* adapters in this folder as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found those files. They were in a different folder, though (Breeze.Client\Scripts\IBlade). The full documentation is very good. Some small documentation about the adapters would be very beneficial.